# How to update apollo cache state BEFORE mutation, for actions like Like, Upvote etc.?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, apollo-client

I'm making a react app using Apollo client for GraphQL queries, where I want to update upvotes state, so that upvoting doesn't take time for users. If I don't, I have to wait for the mutation to return data, which takes 1 second. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Hi welcome to SO, you should provide some code you try on your own so other users can help you.

Comment: 'optimisticResponse'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `optimisticResponse` is your solution. (as @xadm pointed out)

https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/performance/optimistic-ui/

If you already have implemented the `update` function in your mutation (which is normally used to update your query, otherwise you should), it will be called twice, once instantly with your `optimisticResponse`, and once again with the `server response`.